# Fixed header transparent background problem?

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to put z-index to my header class but still not works. When I scroll down everything is fine about position and following scroll but the background of header becomes transparent.

My css

```
.header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 4%;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 70px;
}

.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        animation: smoothScroll 1s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes smoothScroll {
        0% {
            transform: translateY(-70px);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translateY(0px);
        }
    }
```

My js

```
if ($('#wpadminbar')[0])
        $('.header').css('top', '32px')

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sticky = $('.header'),
            scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            sticky.addClass('fixed');
            sticky.css("background-position","fixed");
            body.css("padding-top", "70px");
        } else {
            sticky.removeClass('fixed');
            body.css("padding-top", "none");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? It's unclear what you want and what problem you are experiencing

Comment: Can you also post your html?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with addding another background to ".fixed" class. So it is okay now.